# Uploading new version of my flutter app to google play fails - Version code 1 has already been used

Tags: flutter, google-play

In the Goolge Play Developer Console, I'm trying to upload a new version of my already successfully released app.

I go to: "App Bundle Explorer" -> "Upload new release" in the top right corner -> but then get the error message:

[image: error message]

In the release history there are no bundles to delete, also in the App Bundle Explorer there are no release drafts to delete:

[image: bundle history]

I have pumbed my version in the flutter pubspec.yml, then ran `flutter clean`, then `flutter pub get` and then rebuild the bundle with `flutter build appbundle` but still, somehow, google thinks it's version 1.0.0

In the release overview:

[image]

Comment: The build number should be increased for each build, that's why u get this

Answer (score 0):

After many tries it worked, I don't know exactly why, I simply pumbed up the build number as well: `version: 1.0.1+2`
So the `+2` seems to have done the trick, but that's weird because in the google docs it only says that the version number (1.0.1) needs to increased.